# how to remove links and show text of categories in woocoomerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help on this one because on the single product page in woocommerce, categories are display with a link.

could it be possible to remove the link and only text shows up

im using this code as of the moment

```
$size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
echo '<li>';
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
echo '</li>';
```

thanks

Comment: So what is your code's output?

Comment: it show like this
Categories: Antique, Carpet Size.
but has links pointing to that category, I only want to show text so that it is not clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like;

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if ( sizeof( $categories ) > 0 ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        echo '<li>' . $cat->name . '</li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: thanks Hüseyin BABAL, it worked great just had some minor changes in styling